# ASP.NET Storing Cross Request Data

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application I have this entity:

```
public class Franchise
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

When each of my users log in, they are associated with a franchise.

There is another entity:

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid FranchiseId {get;set;}
    public virtual Franchise Franchise {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}
    /* other useful client information */
}
```

Depending on my user franchise association will determine which clients they shall see (or are allowed to see)

So equivalent of doing

```
dbContext.Set<Client>().Where(x => x.FranchiseId.Equals(associatedFranchiseId));
```

I was wondering what the options where of storing that `associatedFranchiseId` so each request for data can use that `Id` to select the appropriate dataset.

***APPROACH 1***

I created a service that gets these associations and returns the correct dataset. I thought I could use this in each controller where I need to get the information. But I thought this maybe costly in database lookup terms. It would have to based on the User, so getting that out of the request.

I just am not sure how I would go about doing this.

The process is:

1. User Logs In
2. Application determines the associated franchise
3. User request some information
4. The request uses the associated franchise to select the right dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used something similar and use the `session` and `application` spaces for the objects.

So, when the application fires up load all the franchise objects into `application`:

```
Application["Franchise"] = MethodToLoadFranchiseInfo();
```

You can then access this at anytime via `Franchise f = Application["Franchise"];`

Similarly, for the clients, when they login, load the client info into `Session` in a similar fashion.

The only caveat if that you'll need to refresh the `Application` object when there's an update, and same for the session, or require a log out and log back in.

This way you only have one hit to the database and in memory accessible objects!

*** Edit to Add ***

Just had some more thoughts on this, and probably something I'll look to implement myself. If you put a timestamp in both the `application` and `session` objects, if the session object is older than the `application` object (which will be updated centrally being application wide), then hit the database and refresh the `session` object.

That way you do not get the log out / log back in situation when something is changed by the backend / admin.

Comment: And this won't buckle under say 200 users using it at one time?

Comment: If you start sticking objects in session they have to be serializable. Somewhere in your database you presumably have a 'UserFranchiseID'. I'd keep this in session and get whatever data I want each time I need it. I do this on sites with thousands of concurrent users. Hitting a properly constructed database for data is not costly. What do you do if the user/franchise relationship is all in session in objects and someone (an administrator) changes which franchise the user can see? It won't get updated until next time the user logs in. Big potential security issue.

Comment: yeah that is what I thought, I do have that relationship a table holding those relationships which is what my service currently deals with. I'm just trying to work out what methods I need.

Comment: Depends on how big the objects are, but given a GUID and a string x 200 user you're looking at a few MB of memory... Depends on the spec of the server. In my instance, the session object is referred to throughout the whole application, in every control, so I feel it's worth keeping it accessible rather than the DB hit (and has about 100 concurrent users per instance). As @MartinSmellworse says, if it's just one off, then maybe it's worth the database hit. For me, the `application` object get's updated with an admin update, and users have to log off and back on, which hasn't posed a problem.